# Removing cookie on log-out

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, mern

I'm trying to remove the cookies when a user logs out, I'm using JWT, the cookies sent from the backend to the frontend are httponly so I read that it is not possible to delete them from the frontend, that's why I have created a route in my backend to delete the cookies, but It is not working for me , I don't understand why, how can I remove the cookies ?

These are my **login** and **logout** controllers using Express.js :

```
export const login = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
if (!user)
  return next(createError(404, "Username or Password is not correct !"));

const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
  req.body.password,
  user.password
);
if (!isPasswordCorrect)
  return next(createError(400, "Username or Password is not correct !"));

const token = jwt.sign(
  { id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin },
  process.env.JWT
);

const { password, isAdmin, img, ...otherDetails } = user._doc;
res
  .cookie("access_token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
  })
  .status(200)
  .json({ ...otherDetails, img });
} catch (error) {
next(error);
}
};

export const logout = async (req, res) => {
// Set token to none and expire after 5 seconds
res.cookie("access_token", "none", {
// expires: new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 1000),
httpOnly: true,
});
res
.status(200)
.json({ success: true, message: "User logged out successfully" });
 };
```

This is my **handleLogout** function which handles the logout :

```
 const handleLogout = async () => {
  try {
  const res = await axios.post(baseURL + "/auth/logout");
  dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT", payload: res.data });
  console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  }
  };
```

and this is my **authContext** :

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
access_token: Cookies.get("access_token") || null,
loading: false,
error: null,
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

const AuthReducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case "LOGIN_START":
  return {
    user: null,
    access_token: null,
    loading: true,
    error: null,
  };
case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
  return {
    user: action.payload,
    access_token: action.payload.access_token,
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  };
case "LOGIN_FAILURE":
  return {
    user: null,
    access_token: null,
    loading: false,
    error: action.payload,
  };
case "LOGOUT":
  // Cookies.remove("access_token");
  return {
    user: null,
    access_token: null,
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  };
case "REGISTER_START":
  return {
    user: null,
    access_token: null,
    loading: true,
    error: null,
  };
case "REGISTER_SUCCESS":
  return {
    user: action.payload,
    access_token: action.payload.access_token,
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  };
case "REGISTER_FAILURE":
  return {
    user: null,
    access_token: null,
    loading: false,
    error: action.payload,
  };
  default:
  return state;
  }
  };

  export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
  Cookies.set("access_token", state.access_token, { httpOnly: true });
  }, [state.user, state.access_token]);
  return (
<AuthContext.Provider
  value={{
    user: state.user,
    access_token: state.access_token,
    loading: state.loading,
    error: state.error,
    dispatch,
  }}
  >
  {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
  };
```